# Need for module.parent in the following node.js code

Tags: node.js

```
const PORT = 3000;
const HOST = 'localhost';

var express = require('express'),
    http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer(app);

var app = express();

const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();

const io = require('socket.io');

if (!module.parent) {
    server.listen(PORT, HOST);
    const socket  = io.listen(server);

    socket.on('connection', function(client) {
        const subscribe = redis.createClient()
        subscribe.subscribe('realtime');

        ...
        ... 
        });
});
}
```

I stumbled upon this piece of code in one of the sites , In the above code I want to know the reason why the condition (!module.parent) is used ??? Whats the need for using it ??

Answer (score 1):

If there is no module.parent it probably means that the module is being run on its own rather than being used in another program. If the !module.parent block is in a utility module I would guess that it is code for a test or developer tool. In a program that does stuff on it's own (e.g. a webserver), it would probably be the main entry point and the purpose of using it would be to make it possible to require components of that program without running the program.